# Upgrade old Lacie 2big Quadra 1TB

Tags: external-hard-drive, lacie

I have a (very) old Lacie 2big Quadra with 2 500GB drives. It's USB2.0 but it does feature an esata port so I'm planning on using that for speed.

Would I be able to upgrade these with 2 drives of... lets say 4TB ?
Because it's so old I'm a bit afraid that it won't recognise drives bigger than a certain size.

Comment: Its very unlikely the controller built into the device would recognize anything larger then 2TB.  You would be basically taking a gamble.  You would be better off just buying a new larger Lacie drive of the capacity you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Lacie 2~6tb drives are supported

[image]

[Source](http://knowledge.lacie.com/articles/en_US/FAQ/007731en?language=en_US&key=ka030000000is3KAAQ&kb=n&wwwlocale=en-us)

Comment: Bought 2 Western Digital Reds of 3TB and they seem to be working fine. Thanks!